# Rearrange an array such that ‘arr[j]’ becomes ‘i’ if ‘arr[i]’ is ‘j’ with Modulo

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, modulo

I tried to solve the next problem from geeksforgeek [website](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rearrange-array-arrj-becomes-arri-j/).
Given an array of size n where all elements are in range from 0 to n-1, change contents of arr[] so that arr[i] = j is changed to arr[j] = i.
I saw a solution using modulo:

> during one scan
>   arr[arr[i]%n] += n*i
>   and in the next scan 
>   arr[i]/=n

his explanation:

> What i did here was this, I knew that every location will have an element less than n since it has to represent an index of the array, For any number x, such that x is less than n, x%n = x basically when i write, arr[arr[i]%n] and if arr[i]=j
>   i'm accessing the element at arr[j]
>   now you'll notice , i'm incrementing each such element with n*i
>   at this step, i'm storing two elements in one location,
>   For eg: suppose arr[2]=5 and arr[5]=4 and there are 6 elements in total
>   i'll make arr[arr[2]%6]=arr[5%6]=arr[5]= 4+12 i.e. 4 + 2*6
>   which is equal to 16 now this contains both the numbers, if i wan't the original number, i.e. during the first scan when i'm changing all the values, i write arr[5]%6 = (4 + 2*6)%6 = 4%6 + 2*6%6 = 4 + 0 = 4 and during the second scan, when i want to update the array to the final resultant arr[5]/6 = (4 +2*6)/6 = 4/6 + 2*6/6 = 0 + 2 = 2 I hope this explanation helps you, all the best

But I can't understand the logic/math behind it. can someone explain in a mathematical way the logic of the method?

Comment: I actually didn't get the same answer at all.
arr = [1 4 5 0 2 3];

n = 6; 
i = 4;
arr[arr[4]%6] += 6 * 4;
arr[2] += 24;
arr[2] = 29;
arr[4] = 2 / 6;
arr[4] = 0;

Comment: @InfinityCounter You should continue on arr[2]. arr[2] = 29 -> (2nd scan) arr[2] = 29 / 6 => arr[2] = 4

Comment: can't understand why no one can give me an answer. I  tried to edit my question, maybe now it's more clear.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to store two numbers in the range 0..n-1 in one array element. Say if you want to store x and y you actually set the element to z=n*x+y. You can retrieve x by doing z/n and y by doing z%n.

The solution now puts the new numbers into the array (in the x slot) without disturbing the old ones (still in the y slot) using the above trick. In the second pass, the old numbers are removed.